# Prove a point is inside a circle through 3 other points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

This question builds upon a previous question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548807/is-at-least-1-of-4-non-concyclic-points-contained-in-the-circle-through-the-othe)

The answers helped me understand that for $4$ points that are not concyclic, and for which no $3$ fall on a straight line, of the $4$ circles that can be drawn through triples of the points, exactly $1$ or $2$ of the circles will contain the point they don't pass through.

I'm looking for an elementary proof (i.e. one that a high school geometry student could understand) as to why a point must be contained in a circle through $3$ given points. Consider the diagram below:

[image]

DLeMeur's answer to my original question helped me understand that circle $ABD$ will contain $C$ if and only if $D$ is placed in one of the gray areas. The arguments that I can make for this are only sort of convincing, but not really "air tight".

Case 1: $D$ is in the circular segment cut off by chord $\overline{AB}$. Then circle $ABD$ has a greater radius than circle $ABC$, and since $D$ and $C$ are on opposite sides of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, $C$ must be contained in circle $ABD$.

Case 2: $D$ is outside circle $ABC$, on the same side of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ as point $C$. Again, circle $ABD$ has greater radius than circle $ABC$, thus the entire portion of circle $ABC$ below $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ is contained in circle $ABD$.

These arguments seem like they are missing some details. For instance, if someone asked, "How do you know circle $ABD$ has greater radius than circle $ABC$?" I do not have a good answer. I would appreciate any input!

Comment: By calculating the values of the result when computing the circle equation and the line equation with D, negative or positive , you will get the result. To determine the proper values you may calculate it for one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you argument is almost perfect, and you even do not need to ask (and answer) the question which circle has a larger radius. It suffices to know that two distinct circles can intersect in at most two points ([Euclid,Elements, Book III, Proposition 10](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII10.html)).

Let two distinct circles intersect in two points. Draw the straight line through the intersection points. The line splits the plane in two half-planes. Consider one of the half-planes. Due to the Proposition cited above a part of one circle will be completely inside the part of the other circle in this half-plane. And in the other half-plane the relation will be opposite, i.e. the circle which was "inside" in one half-plane will be "outside" in the other half-plane.

This suffices to prove your claim. Just pick a point $D$ in a corresponding region, draw the circle  $ABD$ and consider its relation to the circle $ABC$ in view of the above statement.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I realized that, with the exception of points $A$ and $B$, circle $ABD$ must be entirely in the gray regions, or entirely in the white regions in my diagram.

Comment: Indeed, this is the key observation.

Answer (score 1):

Let O be the center of the originial circle. Produce OD to cut the original circle at D'.

[image]

Follow the sizes of the marked angles and we will arrive at R > r.

Note-1. The numerical values of the angles are for comparisons

Note-2. If D is an interior point of $\triangle ABD'$, $\angle ADB \gt \angle AD'B$ is a fact.